# Vue2 prerender-spa-plugin - all generated index.html files have the same root content after build

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, prerender

I have a working Vue 2 project. I wanted to add the prerender feature to that project. I, therefore, installed the `prerender-spa-plugin` and did some necessary configurations in the `vue.config.js` file. I added a couple of routes (eg: `home` and `about`) for prerendering. When I build the project a separate folder for `about` is getting created, but unfortunately, the `index.html` file inside the `about` folder has the same content as the root `index.html`.

Sharing the related references of my project:

```js
// vue.config.js
const path = require('path')
const PrerenderSpaPlugin = require('prerender-spa-plugin')

const productionPlugins = [
  new PrerenderSpaPlugin({
    staticDir: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    routes: ['/', '/about']
  })
]

module.exports = {
  transpileDependencies: [
    'vuetify'
  ],
  configureWebpack: (config) => {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
      config.plugins.push(...productionPlugins)
    }
  },
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.module
      .rule('pdf-loader')
      .test(/\.pdf$/)
      .use('file-loader')
      .loader('file-loader')
      .end()
  }
}
```

```js
// routes.js
export default [
  {
    path: '',
    component: resolve => require(['@/views/PublicSite/Home/Index.vue'], resolve),
    meta: { title: '' }
  },
  {
    path: '/about',
    name: 'about',
    component: resolve => require(['@/views/PublicSite/About.vue'], resolve),
    meta: { title: 'About' }
  }
}
```

```vue
// App.vue
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-main class="primary darken-4">
      <router-view></router-view>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

```vue
// About.vue
<template>
  <div>
    This is the About page.
  </div>
</template>
```

```html
// index.html
<html lang="en" style="overflow: hidden">
  <head>
    ...
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <!-- built files will be auto-injected -->
  </body>
</html>
```

```json
// package.json
...
  "devDependencies": {
    "@mdi/font": "^5.9.55",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-pwa": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-standard": "^5.1.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "prerender-spa-plugin": "^3.4.0",
    "sass": "~1.32.6",
    "sass-loader": "^10.0.0",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "~2.4.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.7.0"
  }
...
```

I need a suggestion on what wrong I am doing in the configuration.

*PS: I had done some hands-on on a new Vue 2 project with webpack-simple.*